# Looking for a movie where a cannibal lady tries to eat a whole group of people

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

A group of people who live in a post-apocalyptic world and receive, by chance, a new female member.

She is a cannibal who joins the group just to help the member of her other group to kill and eat the other guys.

The first group lives in a hospital.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Tooth and Nail*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooth_and_Nail_%28film%29) from After Dark productions seems to fit the description pretty well;

> *Tooth and Nail is a **post-apocalyptic movie** where mankind has depleted all fossil fuel reserves and civilization has collapsed. **A
>   group of survivors** called Foragers take cover in an **abandoned
>   hospital** where the group attempt to re-build society. After **saving
>   a young girl from being killed** and eaten by a group of vicious
>   cannibals called Rovers, the Foragers **find themselves on the run
>   from the cannibals**, who stalk the survivors and brutally kill them
>   off one-by-one as the Foragers begin to fight back, causing a chaotic
>   battle of blood and mayhem.*